# How can I model wings with aerodynamic properties in Simscape Multibody?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I am currently designing a Simscape Multibody model of my drone. My drone is a three-armed device, which somewhat resembles the rotors of a helicopter.

The drone is supposed to rotate around itself, using a motor on each arm. Furthermore, each arm will have a wing attached to produce the lift required.

The initial purpose will be to control the RPMs of the motors as well as the pitch of the wings.

Currently I have a model without the wings, so I am looking for a way to model wings that do have some aerodynamic properties, that would be able to create some force upwards (lift) from the spinning motion.

How can I integrate wings (or other forms of artificial lift) in to my model?

[3D Model of the drone with motors (generated from Simulink)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfbqZ.png)

Comment: This reads as you are looking for us to do a massive work. SO will help with specific problems, not with entire projects

Comment: You're completely right! Sorry for the inconvenience. To be more specific I guess my question could be whether or not Simscape has blocks that can be customized in regards to its physical properties ie. have it create a force in one direction dependent on another objects velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

A) Use [Aerospace Blockset](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/index.html) for ready-to-use aerodynamic forces

B) Compute your own simplified aerodynamic forces (with Simscape Physical-Signal blocks or Simulink blocks) based on relative orientation, cross-sectional area and speed of your solid wrt the air.

Both options would require sensing the relative orientation and speed of the drone, using the [sensing option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ug/motion-sensing.html) on the [6-DOF Joint](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ref/6dofjoint.html).

[Here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64648-matlab-and-simulink-racing-lounge-vehicle-modeling-with-simscape-multibody)'s an example of using Simscape Multibody together with Aerospace Blockset, but for ground vehicles.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the answer. I went with the second option and my model (however simplified) seems to work the way its intended! 
I did opt for the Revolute Joint for my wings rather thant the 6-DOF Joint, since the wing has to be constrained in its angular displacement.